# select statement not working c# desktop application

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying following code in c# desktop application and trying to search records with specific **exchange name** not using a primary key

```
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from DataTable  where ExchangeName =" + txtExchangeSearch.Text, con);
adapt.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

Comment: If `txtExchangeSearch.Text` is a text you should probably use `='" + txtExchangeSearch.Text + "'"`

Comment: do a google search as well and learn how to use parameters or use the `string.Format( "{0}" , ) ` construct..

Comment: Hi, Another important point is that your sql is subject to sql injection attacks. You should change it so that it uses SqlParameter: select * from DataTable where ExchangeName=@exchname .... var p = new SqlParameter("exchname",txtExchangeSearch.Text)

Comment: @MethodMan ok sir i will, thanks,

Comment: @RickHodder thanks for the tip..!